# ¿Se pueden trazar rectangulos de sumas de Riemann con Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

ya tracé el gráfico de la ecuación x**2 con Jupyter con el código:

```
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.abc import x
eq=x**2
plot(eq,(x,-2,2),ylim=(-1,2),line_color="g")
```

que nos da la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero también es necesario dibujar unos rectángulos que aproximan el área como las sumas de Riemann en un intervalo del eje x, por ejemplo [0,1], mas o menos así:

[image: funcion_graficada]

¿Alguién sabe si se puede hacer con Python 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Claro que se puede, con Python el cielo es el límite... XD.

Bromas aparte, no especificas que suma de Riemann quieres aplicar (derecha, izquierda, máximo, mínimo). Voy a usar la suma izquierda de acuerdo a tu ejemplo:

Para la gráfica uso `matplotlib` y `NumPy` para los arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def riemannplot(f, a, b, ra, rb, n):
    # f es la función 
    # a y b son los limites del eje x para graficar la funcion f
    # ra y rb son los limites del intervalo en el eje x del que queremos calcular la suma
    # n es el numero de rectangulos que calcularemos

    atenuacion = (b-a)/100
    x = np.arange(a, b+atenuacion, atenuacion)
    plt.plot(x, f(x), color='green')

    delta_x = (rb-ra)/n
    riemannx = np.arange(ra, rb, delta_x)
    riemanny = f(riemannx)
    riemann_sum = sum(riemanny*delta_x)

    plt.bar(riemannx,riemanny,width=delta_x,alpha=0.5,facecolor='orange')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)')
    plt.title('Suma izquierda de Riemann para f(x)')
    plt.figtext(0.1,0.02, "Suma de Riemann: " + str(riemann_sum), color='r')
    plt.show()



def f(x):
    return x**2

riemannplot(f, 0, 1.1, 0, 1, 10)
```

No se si tienes que hacerlo mediante `SymPy` obligatoriamente o no. No obstante, la idea básica es la misma uses el metodo que uses para graficar:

❶ Dividir el intervalo en n partes iguales, obteniendo los valores de x que separan cada rectangulo.

❷ Para cada triangulo calcular su altura, para lo cual basta con pasar cada valor de x obtenido antes a la función.

❸ Ya solo queda graficar el histograma usando para ello las alturas y el ancho de cada barra que es el incremento de x (longitud del intervalo/n)

La gráfica que nos crea es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no quieres usar una función auxiliar puedes pasar tu función como un string a `riemannplot()` usando `SymPy` para ello:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import S, symbols
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify


def riemannplot(f, a, b, ra, rb, n):
    x = symbols('x')
    f = lambdify(x, S(f),'numpy')

    atenuacion = (b-a)/100
    xs = np.arange(a, b+atenuacion, atenuacion)
    plt.plot(xs, f(xs), color='green')

    delta_x = (rb-ra)/n
    riemannx = np.arange(ra, rb, delta_x)
    riemanny = f(riemannx)
    riemann_sum = sum(riemanny*delta_x)

    plt.bar(riemannx,riemanny,width=delta_x,alpha=0.5,facecolor='orange')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)')
    plt.title('Suma izquierda de Riemann para f(x)')
    plt.figtext(0.1,0.02, "Suma de Riemann: " + str(riemann_sum), color='r')
    plt.show()
```

Ahora puedes llamar a `riemannplot()` de esta forma:

```
riemannplot('x**2', 0, 1.1, 0, 1, 10)
```

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, muy interesante la manera de tratar los ejemplos.